# Spark Job server context user change at run time

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0, spark-jobserver

How can I change the user of the context created in Spark Job Server?
I want to change the user which I am getting on sparkSession.sparkContext.sparkUser();

Answer (score 0):

follow the below steps.

```
[root@localhost bin]# export HADOOP_USER_NAME=praveen //set this environment variable
[root@localhost bin]# ./spark-shell // start the spark shell

scala> sc.sparkUser //Spark context available as sc.
res0: String = praveen
```

By this way you can change the sparkUser value.